# Integral-Differential Equation Modeling Banked Turn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Solve this equation for the function $y(x)$:

$y' = \alpha \left(\int\sqrt{1 + y'^2} dx \right)^2$

Of course this must first be solved for $y'$ and then integrated to get $y$.

The following is not directly relevant to the problem, but gives the context in which it came up: 
Consider a road of $n$ lanes where the velocities of cars on successive lanes form an arithmetic progression.  Now there is a turn of radius taken equal across all lanes.  Each lane is banked so as to have no friction (then it must have the angle $\theta$ where $\frac{v^2}{r}=g\tan\theta$).  Now take $n$ to infinity, keeping each lane of equal width and holding the minimum and maximum velocities (on the left and right sides of the road) fixed. Now $\tan\theta=\frac{dy}{dx}$ is proportional to $v^2$, and $v$ is proportional to $\int\sqrt{1 + y'^2} dx$.

Comment: Is that a definite integral or indefinite?

Comment: I am not sure that there is a "nice" solution. Wolfram Alpha just gives the solution in terms of an elliptic integral however I think it's just a rewriting of what you have.

Comment: @Maesumi It's an indefinite integral.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I was able to get $x$ as a function of $y'$ with elliptic integrals, using Wolfram Alpha.  But I was looking for $y$ as a function of $x$.  Do you know how to get that with elliptic integrals?

Comment: @Amzoti yes that gives $y''=2\alpha\sqrt{y'(1+y'^2)}$.  I can get $x$ as a function of $y'$ with this using elliptic integrals, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: I just doing this for fun, so there aren't any particular rules I have to follow.